# Can one define quantized universal enveloping algebras in a basis-free way?

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

(For the background, I am learning about quantum groups — essentially in order to understand crystal/global/canonical bases in the context of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244275/nice-basis-for-highest-weight-irreducible-module-of-a-simple-lie-algebra) — from the books by Jantzen and by Hong&Kang and the 1995 paper "On Crystal Bases" by Kashiwara, along with a few others.)

The definition given of a quantized universal enveloping algebra (at least in the sources mentioned in the above parenthesis, or [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group#Drinfeld.E2.80.93Jimbo_type_quantum_groups)) is an explicit construction by generators and relations.  What I would like to understand is whether this is merely convenient (simply construct the objects we care about and then work with them) or if there is some deeper reason:

> Is there an alternative definition of the quantized universal enveloping algebra of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ that does not involve giving an explicit construction with generators and relations?

(I am willing to restrict myself to finite dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$ if that helps.)

This could mean, for example, a combination of one of the following ideas that come to my mind:

- Abstractly defining a quantum deformation of the universal enveloping algebra of a semisimple Lie algebra.
- Defining a particular condition on Hopf algebras (along the lines of "the category of <mumble mumble mumble> modules is semisimple") and then *classifying* the algebras satisfying this condition using root systems just like one does for finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebras.
- Describing the quantized universal enveloping algebra as solution to a universal problem (or representing some functor).
- Perhaps only in the classical ($A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$, $D_n$) cases, constructing the algebra starting from a "standard representation" that itself can be obtained from basis-free data (such as a vector space perhaps with a quadratic form attached to it, or something).
- Using the "canonical basis" to define the algebra in the first place.

(Maybe some of these ideas are completely stupid.  I merely list them in order to explain the sort of thing I'd be happy to see.)

Even a construction that still involves generators and relations but avoids choosing a basis of the root system would be interesting to see.

As things stand, I don't even understand to what extent the $e,f,k$ generators of the algebra can be recovered from the algebra itself, or what choices have to be made for that (this is admittedly a different question, but I imagine it is strongly related), so answers along that line are also welcome.

Comment: A related question?  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105221/quantum-groups-not-via-presentations

Comment: Probably [Vogel's approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogel_plane) could be used - it builds only on invariant quantities like Casimir eigenvalues. Quantization has been worked on by [Westbury](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08307)

Comment: @LSpice Good catch, I wouldn't object to my question being marked as a duplicate, although André Henriques's question is perhaps more restrictive, but Theo Johnson-Freyd's answer to it is definitely enlightening.  I'll let other people decide whether to close this.

Comment: Quantum geometric Satake can at least recover the category of representations of the quantum group, not sure if it can recover the fiber functor as well: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0705.4571

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, sorry; I didn't mean to say that it was a duplicate (the answers seem meaningfully different), literally just that it appeared to be an interesting related question.

Comment: The link in [Qiaochu's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275841/can-one-define-quantized-universal-enveloping-algebras-in-a-basis-free-way#comment681670_275841) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4571

Answer (score 13):

For complex simple $\mathfrak g$, Drinfeld ([1986](https://web.archive.org/web/20170916141114/http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1986.1/), p. 807) already characterized his $\mathrm U_h\mathfrak g$ as the unique (up to equivalence and change of parameter) deformation of $\mathrm U\mathfrak g$ admitting a “quantum Cartan involution”, i.e. an algebra automorphism and coalgebra antiautomorphism extending the Cartan involution and for which comultiplication is cocommutative on the Cartan subalgebra. (This exact statement is from Shnider ([1991](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54707877/f18), Cor. 3), more details and a proof in Shnider-Sternberg ([1993](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1287162), p. 285).)

Comment: I just went and found a copy of Shnider–Sternberg *cough* somewhere *cough*, and, irrespective of the mathematics, am pleased to see on the referenced page that probably-dying artefact of e-mail mangling + TeX, the string "¿From" as which TeX renders ">From" in Computer Modern.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know the answer in general. But towards the end of the OP you say:

> "Even a construction that still involves generators and relations but avoids choosing a basis of the root system would be interesting to see"

Motivated from this remark, I was wondering whether [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/126461/85967) description might be of interest for your purposes. If yes, you can find more details at C. Kassel's book on Quantum groups, ch. $VI$, sect. $2$, p. 125-126 (Prop. 2.1, 2.2).

Comment: Of course, p. 125–126 are excerpted from the otherwise-generous Google Books preview of Chapter VI ….